# Find if a unique user updated their inventory after the initial month - Excel/GoogleSheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

this is my first time looking for help at a forum so i feel excited,

I need to make a formula to find if an user has an stock update on the first month and never updated their stock again,

I have the data for their stock update and also the month they're doing it as a month sequence but i cant solve how to do it i think its maybe an IF statement to check distinct emails but i don't know how to do it.

I need something like this:

[table desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCdgl.png)

UPDATE: Testing table of how my source data looks:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ipNi_ioxtlYWvayEn6BQeQjkYR_pilZJoWPdzVenNHg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but is it `=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B2)>0)` what you're after?

Comment: Hello @P.b thanks for the answer, this helps me to know if there was an update depending on the month sequence, but the problem is if the email has more than 2 entries the formula wont help :/

Comment: You may want to share how your source table and data look like. Have a look in GROUPBY in PowerQuery or in the FILTER and UNIQUE cell formula expressions

Comment: @Milkman What would be your desired output from given sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Can try `COUNTIFS()`

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,A2,$B$2:$B,">0")>1,"No","Yes")
```

For array approach can try-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B,">0")>1,"No","Yes")))
```

[image]